# How to increase quality of image through imagemagick binary convert?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, exec, imagemagick-convert

I'm working in an image conversion using **imageMagick binary convert**. When i resize a small image into a larger image and also increase the quality of image.
Here's my sample code:

```
$img = 'old_image.png';
$path1= 'new_img.png';
exec("convert $img -quality 100% -density 600  -resize 2480x3508 -depth 400 $path1");
```

When i used this command its working fine and it convert large image with loss of quality.
When i need to increase quality by using `sharpen 50%` code in `exec` command it doesn't create a proper image and no response in `exec command`.

```
$img = 'old_image.png';
$path1= 'new_img.png';
exec("convert $img -sharpen 99% -quality 100% -density 600  -resize 2480x3508 -depth 400 $path1");
```

Here I'm using **image magick binary convert**. How to achieve this image quality. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think sharpen works like blur and takes an argument of `{radius}x{sigma}`

What version are you using?  Maybe look at some of the docs that correspond to it...

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur